# Make HTML5 details tag to take maximum available height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an HTML page with header/content/footer that uses flexbox model and contains `<details>` tag.
I need to make details content use maximum available height, meaning that when in opened state its content should occupy all space in its container (except for summary of course).

Here is my HTML/CSS code (http://jsfiddle.net/rtojycvk/2/):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="main">
        Some text before details
        <details class="details" open>
            <summary>Details summary</summary>
            <div class="content">Details content</div>
        </details>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.main {
    background-color: cyan;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.content {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    flex: 1;
}
.details {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

As you can see, the details tag itself takes all the available space, but not its content.

P.S. I need this to work only in Chrome.

Comment: Try adding  .content{height: 100vh;}

Comment: It makes content height equal to window height that is not what I want

Comment: "I need to make details content to use maximum available height."  It will make content-details fill the details summary container.

Comment: But it will extend the page size. So, when the header is visible then bottom part of the details and footer will be below the view port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rtojycvk/16/

use position absolute on content, position relative on details, and calc() css (to offset the summary height)

```
.content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    flex: 1;
    display:flex;
    position:absolute;
    height:  calc(100% - 18px);
    width: 100%;
}
.details {
    background-color: gray;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position:relative;
}
```

hope this helps! (I changed the colors cause they were a bit bright for me :p)

Comment: It looks better, then previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27823886/3079960), but it have an issue - you should know the size of the summary

Comment: in addition, it is needed to add `.content { overflow: hidden; }` to prevent overlapping of content and footer when window is too small

Comment: @Norfolc ahh i see what you mean with both comments. as for the first, are you open to using jquery or are you purely looking for a css answer? if just css, the current answer is the extent that my knowledge can help you.  if you're open to jquery, i can solve the issue of needing to know the size of the summary. lmk

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioned .content and details relative. 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtojycvk/15/)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.main {
  background-color: cyan;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.content {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 97%;
  width: 100%;
}
details {
  position: relative;
}
summary{
  height: 3%;
}
.details {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Can you adjust: details at 100%, summary at x% .content at 100%-x% to your needs?

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer not to set absolutes positions, or can't do it, there is another way to accomplish it: using `vh` for height of `.content`:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100vh;
  background: orange;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
  background: pink;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  min-height: 25px;  /* (or max-height, or both!)  */
  max-height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
}

.main {
  background-color: cyan;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 20vh);   /*  10vh * 2 (.header + .footer sizes) */
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 20vh);  /*  10vh * 2 (.header + .footer sizes) */
}

.details {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">Header</header>
    <main class="main">
        Some text before details
        <details class="details" open>
            <summary>Details summary</summary>
            <div class="content">Details content</div>
        </details>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Fiddle's here: [http://jsfiddle.net/ALXWebDev/wxm0v49c/](http://jsfiddle.net/ALXWebDev/wxm0v49c/7/)

Hope it helps!